# Как склонять слово "глечик"?

Tags: склонение, диалекты

Глечик - у нас в деревне так называли пористую крынку для стекания сыворотки из простокваши. Родительный падеж всегда был `нет (чего?) "глечка"`. Сейчас общаюсь со староверами, они утверждают - `нет (чего?) "глечика"`.
Как будет правильнее? По правилам русского языка, формально, староверы правы. Но, сколько помню воронежские говоры, там (ик/ек) работало по-другому. Или, как всегда, с диалектами, и так, и эдак?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратимся к украинскому первоисточнику:

> **[ГЛЕ́ЧИК, а, ч.](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)**
>   1. Те саме, що глек 1. Мати загадала їй зібрати **з глечика** сметану та накришити сала (Н.-Лев., II, 1956, 279); Метушливо кинулася [Груня] до печі, вийняла пахучий глечик пареного молока, що аж присмажилося (Горд., II, 1959, 285); На тину красувалися горщик і два глечики (Шиян, Гроза.., 1956, 404); * У порівн. У других ніздрі, як наперсток, а в нього, мов навмисне, як глечики (Донч., VI, 1957, 64).